# Mono.Cecil: Create Instruction from string

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

How can i turn strings like these:

```
"call        System.Console.WriteLine" 
"ldstr       \"hello\""
```

into Intructions with Operands?

Comment: I don't think you can, `Console.WriteLine` has many overloads, so `call        System.Console.WriteLine` is ambiguous. Where did you get that string from? What is it that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @svick im getting the il code from LinqPad5 and im trying to make a program that programmically replaces il in methods using strings as ilcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you now how to use `Mono.Cecil` (or `Reflection.Emit`), the question is more generally about parsing text to code actions.

You have some ways to do that and I can just show you an hint and you can choose your way.

First of all you need some prerequisites **(If you IL text is a valid IL code these prerequisites already exist for you)**.
For example, you can't guess what `Console.WriteLine` is. `Console` is an assembly, type, method? same questions on `WriteLine`. And even if we know that `WriteLine` is a method, which overload we need to choose? and what about generics? So you need set a contract that define for example that the dot is the delimiter and the first section is assembly, the second is namespace, and so on.

For example:

`"mscorlib.System.Console.WriteLine(string)"` will be translated to `System.Console.WriteLine(string)`

After you have a strict contract, you need a few steps (for the `WriteLine` example):

1. Resolve the `Assembly` and get is `ModuleDefinition`
2. Resolve and import the `Type`
3. Resolve and import the `MethodReference` describe the requested method
4. Emit the call

One way to do that, is to keep structure of opcodes and their required action.

For example, we know that `call` instruction is need to emit call to static method (in most of the cases) so you need to send the operand to `ParseStaticCall`, there you need to parse the string and emit the call instruction

Pseudo code:

```
new Dictionary<string, Tuple<OpCode, Action<string>>>
{
    {
        "call",
        Tuple.Create<OpCode, Action<string>>
          (OpCodes.Call,ParseStaticCall)
    }
};


static void ParseStaticCall(Opcpde opcode,
                            string call,
                            ILProcessor processor)
{
    string assembly, namespaceName, type, method;
    int numOfParameters;

    var moduleDefenition = AssemblyResolver.Resolve(assembly).MainModule;

    var methodReference = 
        new ReferenceFinder(moduleDefenition).
            GetMethodReference(typeof (Console),
                md => md.Name == methodName &&
                md.Parameters.Count == numOfParameters);
        processor.Emit(opcode, methodReference);
}
```

`AssemblyResolver` is an helper class to find assembly by name and path (can be a constant path). `ReferenceFinder` is an helper class that find type\method in a specific module.

So you need to create method and `ILProccesor` for the method body, then for every string you have, you need to separate the instruction opcode form the operand, then look in dictionary for the required action and pass the opcode, the operand as string and the `ILProccesor`.